# Where are startup programs stored on Windows?

Tags: windows, boot

To clarify, I'm not referring to programs that run on user logon, but rather to programs that run when Windows starts up. I would like to make a program run on startup as SYSTEM by placing it in a specific directory.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=startup+administrator

Comment: There is no folder where you can move programs, you will have to configure your system to run the program with elevated permissions via the methods linked in the search and duplicate.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll try that